# Javascript file having html tags after loading

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a js file in my web application project(C#) and when I run my application then in dynamic js file there are some html on the top this js file

and so on

I am not able to call the function that are in js file . 
what may be reason that html showing in js file

Comment: can u access the file from url in your browser ? could be an error serving the file ..

Comment: how to you mean "dynamic js file" ? how to you call it, how to you add it to your page ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the html on top of js file and then call the function.

Comment: I got the solution.There was somthing wrong with jquery. After using no conflict its working fine..